# How to share data via Output between Angular Elements and Angular Project

Tags: angular

I import an Angular Element in an Angular 6 project. The @Input works well but the @Output doesn't. When I try to receive the message, I get the return *{"isTrusted":false}*

angular element html:

```
 <button (click)="handleClick()">{{show}}</button>
```

angular element component:

```
 @Input() show = '';
 @Output() action = new EventEmitter<string>();

 handleClick() {
   this.action.emit('test');
 }
```

project html declaring element:

```
   <menu-test show="John" (action)="receiveMessage($event)"></menu-test>
```

project component:

```
receiveMessage($event) {
  // here $event returns {"isTrusted":false}
}
```

Comment: It seems to a script error - are you emitting your event from different domain ?

Comment: no, the custom element code is inside my angular project.
in my module: import '../../elements/menu-test.js';

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the details in `receiveMessage`, but I arrived at this question with the same issue. In my case I was trying to do

```js
receiveMessage($event) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify($event));
}
```

which only output `{"isTrusted":false}`. However, if I output the actual event,

```js
receiveMessage($event) {
  console.log($event);
}
```

I get an actual `CustomEvent` object. This object has a `isTrusted` property that is in fact false, but it also contains a `details` property that contains my emitted object. In your case, I'd expect `$event.detail` to be equal to `"test"`